# Why not use jQuery with Vue.js for AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm trying to optimize references on a greenfield project that uses Vue.js. It also uses Bootstrap, with requires jQuery for some of its magic, so jQuery is already in the mix. While I have no intention of using its DOM manipulation tools, jQuery is already there, so is there a good reason to not just use it for the AJAX calls from within my Vue components? The syntax between jQuery and axios is fairly similar, so if I can avoid adding another library, that would be groovy.

Comment: Have you considered just using vanilla `fetch`?

Comment: IMO, if jQuery is required and utilised by your app. There is no real reason to include another library to handle AJAX. @SebastianSpeitel beat me to it! Use fetch and polyfill with jQuery - https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel yes, but I'd have to polyfill for that anyway for compatibility which seems like a half-step.

Comment: jQuery and Vue.js sounds bad together because they are solution of different generation. You should use `fetch` and drop jQuery by default because it is obselete, especially in new project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reasons behind the "don't use jQuery for AJAX in Vue" mantra are:

- If `$` is already available in the component, it's more tempting to query or manipulate the DOM instead of using `v-model`, `v-if`, `:class`, etc..
- Axios is an excellent library for AJAX and uses less data than jQuery.
- Using jQuery could lead to a hard to maintain mix between jQuery plugins and Vue components.

My recommendation is to write a simple `api.js` helper file with methods such as:

```
api.get(url) 
api.post(url, data)
...etc.
```

These methods may use `$.ajax` internally, but when you'll upgrade to Bootstrap 5 ([which doesn't require jQuery](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/23586)) you can change the implementation to something else.

Comment: Yeah, I get all of that, but Bootstrap _today_ uses jQuery so it's already there. BS5 doesn't even have a roadmap or active dev yet.

Comment: Aside from the objections above, I don't see an issue with using jQuery.