# How to a pass parameter be a variable onclick and vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to send second parameter like my variable on js, it is a string but i want it to be variable after send it

```
<button id="txt" onclick="activate(this.id, 'group_question.active')" class="kind-btn"type="button">
  <i class='fas fa-poll-h kind-icon'></i>
</button>
<button id="pic" onclick="activate(this.id, 'group_question.active')" class="kind-btn"type="button"style="padding-left: 15px;">
  <i class='fas fa-image kind-icon'style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
</button>
<button id="sound" onclick="activate(this.id, 'group_question.active')" class="kind-btn"type="button">
  <i class="material-icons kind-icon"style="font-size: 31px;top: 8px;margin-bottom: 13px;">music_video</i>
</button>

//js
function activate(id, rec) {
  let saver = rec.replace(/['"]+/g, ''); // i wanna rec be variable for using it to change style
  console.log(typeof saver);
  if (saver != id) {
    $("#" + saver).css({"background-color": "white", "color": "#fe5d87"});
  }
  saver = id;
  $("#" + saver).css({"background-color": "#fe5d87", "color": "white"});

var group_question = new Vue({
  el: '#cr_que',
  data: {
    active: "txt"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this.id` in your vue template. Also, you don't need `jQuery` for this and you also should not use it with `Vue.js`. See: [Why not use jQuery with Vue.js for AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959714/why-not-use-jquery-with-vue-js-for-ajax).

Instead You can write a method, pass a value, and set the data. Then in your template you apply styles if the value matches `:class="type === 'text' && 'selected'"`:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      type: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    activate(type) {
      this.type = type;
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #fe5d87; 
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div id="app">
  <button id="text" @click="activate('text')" class="kind-btn" :class="type === 'text' && 'selected'" type="button">
    <i class='fas fa-poll-h kind-icon' style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
  </button>
  <button id="pic" @click="activate('pic')" class="kind-btn" :class="type === 'pic' && 'selected'" type="button" style="padding-left: 15px;">
    <i class='fas fa-image kind-icon' style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
  </button>
  <button id="sound" @click="activate('sound')" class="kind-btn" :class="type === 'sound' && 'selected'" type="button">
    <i class="material-icons kind-icon" style="font-size: 31px; top: 8px; margin-bottom: 13px;">music_video</i>
  </button>
</div>
```